# Getting a sublist from a list and loops

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have this variable that holds this.

```
['Needie Seagoon', 0.6, 0.8556701030927835, 0.5555555555555556, 0.8297872340425532, 0.978494623655914, 0.7849462365591398, 0.7142857142857143, 0.6436781609195402]
['Eccles', 0.98, 0.9381443298969072, 0.8080808080808081, 0.6947368421052632, 0.8850574712643678, 0.7959183673469388, 0.5161290322580645, 0.875]
['Bluebottle', 0.6421052631578947, 0.9072164948453608, 0.8080808080808081, 0.6382978723404256, 0.4838709677419355, 0.5591397849462365, 1.0, 0.9770114942528736]
['Henry Crun', 0.968421052631579, 0.5979381443298969, 0.5050505050505051, 0.6063829787234043, 0.7204301075268817, 0.4838709677419355, 0.8461538461538461, 0.8275862068965517]
['Minnie Bannister', 0.5368421052631579, 1.0, 0.5252525252525253, 0.5638297872340425, 0.7311827956989247, 0.6236559139784946, 0.7692307692307693, 0.7931034482758621]
['Hercules Grytpype-Thynne', 0.78, 0.6391752577319587, 0.7575757575757576, 0.7052631578947368, 0.5517241379310345, 0.5714285714285714, 0.956989247311828, 0.7613636363636364]
['Count Jim Moriarty', 0.5368421052631579, 0.7010309278350515, 0.5151515151515151, 0.7021276595744681, 0.5913978494623656, 0.7741935483870968, 0.5494505494505495, 0.8505747126436781]
['Major Dennis Bloodnok', 0.54, 0.4845360824742268, 0.5959595959595959, 0.5052631578947369, 0.7586206896551724, 0.5918367346938775, 0.5698924731182796, 0.9431818181818182]
```

Is it best to add these sublists into an array list so say new_li = [] and append the list to that?

I want to loop through each name and their scores to get the mean average of all scores for that student. To loop through this easier I just spliced the list like so:

NOTE: Studentp_file is the list variable for above lists.

```
for line in studentp_file:
answer = line[1:14]
```

The result is a new list that has only the numbers:

```
[0.6, 0.8556701030927835, 0.5555555555555556, 0.8297872340425532, 0.978494623655914, 0.7849462365591398, 0.7142857142857143, 0.6436781609195402]
[0.98, 0.9381443298969072, 0.8080808080808081, 0.6947368421052632, 0.8850574712643678, 0.7959183673469388, 0.5161290322580645, 0.875]
[0.6421052631578947, 0.9072164948453608, 0.8080808080808081, 0.6382978723404256, 0.4838709677419355, 0.5591397849462365, 1.0, 0.9770114942528736]
[0.968421052631579, 0.5979381443298969, 0.5050505050505051, 0.6063829787234043, 0.7204301075268817, 0.4838709677419355, 0.8461538461538461, 0.8275862068965517]
[0.5368421052631579, 1.0, 0.5252525252525253, 0.5638297872340425, 0.7311827956989247, 0.6236559139784946, 0.7692307692307693, 0.7931034482758621]
[0.78, 0.6391752577319587, 0.7575757575757576, 0.7052631578947368, 0.5517241379310345, 0.5714285714285714, 0.956989247311828, 0.7613636363636364]
[0.5368421052631579, 0.7010309278350515, 0.5151515151515151, 0.7021276595744681, 0.5913978494623656, 0.7741935483870968, 0.5494505494505495, 0.8505747126436781]
[0.54, 0.4845360824742268, 0.5959595959595959, 0.5052631578947369, 0.7586206896551724, 0.5918367346938775, 0.5698924731182796, 0.9431818181818182]
```

So I want to add up the values of say the first line and get the average. Then do so for the second, third and so on.

How would I loop this? I can't seem to get the line by line loop going well.

The plan is to add the names back in later.

Thanks.

Comment: You can add those numbers with `sum(answer)`

Comment: `print([sum(x) / len(x) for x in lst])` gives you averages where `lst` is your list.

Answer (score 0):

```
for sublist in list:
    for value in sublist:
        if not isinstance(value, float):
            sublist.remove(value)
    print(sublist)
```

I hope it will fullfill your requiremnets

Answer (score 0):

If we put all the `lists` into one `list` we can then loop through each sublist and calculate the `mean` for each sliced sublist `[1:]` this will skip the first item which is the name of the student

*List comprehension*

```
means = [sum(i[1:])/float(len(i[1:])) for i in l]
```

> ```
> [0.7453022035139001, 0.8116333563690437, 0.7519653356706918, 0.6944792261318251, 0.6928871681167221, 0.7154399707796905, 0.6525961084709853, 0.6236613189972134]
> ```

Expanded Loop:

```
means = []

for i in l:
    means.append(sum(i[1:])/float(len(i[1:])))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.mean()` with a few list comprehensions and a dictionary comprehension to assemble your output:

```
import numpy as np

students = [i[0] for i in data]
scores = [np.mean(np.array(i[1:])) for i in data]
answer = {student: score for student, score in zip(students, scores)}
```

Yields:

```
{'Needie Seagoon': 0.7453022035139001, 'Eccles': 0.8116333563690437, 'Bluebottle': 0.7519653356706919, 'Henry Crun': 0.6944792261318251, 'Minnie Bannister': 0.6928871681167221, 'Hercules Grytpype-Thynne': 0.7154399707796903, 'Count Jim Moriarty': 0.6525961084709853, 'Major Dennis Bloodnok': 0.6236613189972134}
```